# Vue-Router: TypeError: this._router.init is not a function

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I have vue-router installed (within Laravel project), then try to use it:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

then I get this:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in beforeCreate hook: "TypeError: this._router.init is not a function"
```

Interestingly enough, everything was fine previously, but suddenly started getting this message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `vue` with `vue-loader` in your Webpack config
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/409

### UPDATE

Okay, obviously you are initializing the router in a unique way.  Perhaps you are building a State Tag Application rather than a Single Page App.

```
require('./bootstrap');
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'


/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

let home = require('./components/Home.vue'));
let buy = require('./components/Buy.vue');
let home = require('./components/Home.vue');
let sell = require('./components/Sell.vue');
let wallet = require('./components/Wallet.vue');


const routes = [{
        path: '/',
        component: home
    },
    {
        path: '/buy',
        component: buy
    },
    {
        path: '/sell',
        component: sell
    },
    {
        path: '/wallet',
        component: wallet
    }

];

const router = new VueRouter
({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
})

Vue.use(VueRouter);

window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    render: h => h(home) 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this (loader set to vue) is nowhere to be found in the webpack configs of laravel-mix. Maybe another idea?

Comment: Are you sure you have access to Vue from the place where you are calling `Vue.use(VueRouter)` ? Also check that you have `router` key at the root level of your Vue instance and it points to the proper VueRouter instance.

Comment: Everything looks good for me, please take a look at my app.js below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how my app.js looks like:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('home', require('./components/Home.vue'));


let buy = require('./components/Buy.vue');
let home = require('./components/Home.vue');
let sell = require('./components/Sell.vue');
let wallet = require('./components/Wallet.vue');


const routes = [{
        path: '/',
        component: home
    },
    {
        path: '/buy',
        component: buy
    },
    {
        path: '/sell',
        component: sell
    },
    {
        path: '/wallet',
        component: wallet
    }

]

const router = ({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
})

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```