# VueJS passing router to child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How Can I pass router to my child component.

I have this as my router

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
export default function () {
const Router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history', 
    routes : [
      {
        path: '/',
        beforeEnter: ifAuthenticated,
        component: () => {
          return  import('./../container/Index.vue')
        }
      }, 
      {
        path: '/login',
        beforeEnter: ifNotAuthenticated,
        component: () => {
         return import('./../container/logn.vue')
        }
      }
    ],

  })

  return Router
}
```

Now my `"/"` (**index.vue**) route have a component Navbar and the Navbar have a logout button which logs out the user and redirect them to login page

Consider this to be my index.vue (with what I have done)

```
<template>
  <q-layout>
    <Navbar :thisInfo="routerAndStore"/>
 </q-layout>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from "./../components/navbar.vue";
export default {
  name: "PageIndex",
  components: {
    Navbar
  },
  data() {
    return {
      routerAndStore: this
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

And then in my **navbar.vue** I have done something like this

```
<template>
  <div class="nav-pages-main">
      <a @click="logoutUser">
        <h5>Logout</h5>
      </a>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "navbar",
  methods: {
    logoutUser: () => {
      return this.thisInfo.$store.dispatch("GOOGLE_PROFILE_LOGOUT").then(() => {
        this.$router.push("/login");
      });
    }
  },
  props: {
    thisInfo: {
      type: Object
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

but this doesn't seem to be working (**this is coming out to be undefined**), So if someone can help me figure out **how we can pass `this` to our child component**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to Vue-Router official documentation [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html)

Basically, in their use case, the main component (index.vue) take a router as argument and provide `<router-view>`  in its template as placeholder for component that would be rendered based on the current route.

In your code, I see that you use it the other way around using router to render the main component.

```
routes : [
  {
    path: '/',
    beforeEnter: ifAuthenticated,
    component: () => {
      return  import('./../container/Index.vue')
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

Could you try it again using the right way described in the documentation and tell me the result?

Edit: According to the App.vue that you posted (assuming it's the app entry point) then you should provide router to the App component.

```
<template>
    <div id="q-app"> <router-view/> </div>
</template>
<script>
    import router from '/path/to/your/router';

    export default { name: "App", router };
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

The full code for this can be found at Vue-Router [example](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/route-props/app.js)

Comment: Slightly updated my first code snippet. Also I am using Quassar Framework
Also instead of considering it is as index.vue, consider it as home.vue (1/3)

Comment: So If I got your answer correctly (and thanks a lot for answering) and Vue-router Docs correctly, What they are doing in index.vue, In Quassar boiler-plate code that happens in App.vue (not exactly the same). 
This is how App.vue looks `<template>
  <div id="q-app">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App"
};
</script>

<style>
</style>`

Comment: I am not sure since I am new to Vue and Quasar framework. But I think Vue instance is created during the run /build time in `.quasar` based on our configuration in `quasar.config` (equivalent to webpack config).  Again, I am just guessing all this.

Comment: @anny123 Updated the answer with the info that you gave. Hope it helps.

Comment: this throws following errors **Error in beforeCreate hook: "TypeError: this._router.init is not a function"

found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:587
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1733
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1728
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1717
callHook @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2919
Vue._init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4622
.....
...**

Comment: @anny123 you have to initialize vue-router first. Please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51462715/vue-router-typeerror-this-router-init-is-not-a-function